# How to switch between git commits

Tags: git, github, version-control

**Git commits**
e.g. I do six commits for a specific code file, is there a way for me to switch to my previous commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.... you can use their IDs... which you can get from git log.

```
git checkout some-id
```

You can also refer to a branch.

```
git checkout some-branch~3 #3 revisions behind some-branch
```

Or you can use `HEAD` (in other words, your current position) as a reference

```
git checkout HEAD~3 # go back 3 revisions from where I am right now
```

All 3 forms will set up in `detached HEAD state`, just in case. So you will have to checkout a branch later when you want to go back to *normal*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is always a way to do that.
You can make use of `git log --oneline` to see all your commits.
Then copy the commits id, and use `git checkout the+commit_id` to move to the commits you wish.
To go back to where you were, use `git checkout the+branchname`